# Is it possible to migrate pipeline history from one Azure DevOps project to another

Tags: azure-devops, migration, azure-pipelines

I am migrating a hosted Azure DevOps project from one organization to a new organization. I'm using and extending the [Migration Tools for Azure DevOps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration) to do much of the work in this. One challenge that I am encountering is pipeline history.

Ideally, we would like to preserve the history (builds, releases, artifacts, etc.) in this process, however I cannot find a way using the exposed APIs to do this. Has anyone found a way to do this, or a reasonable workaround?

Comment: No. It's better to accept that most historical data is not an option for migration and proceed accordingly.

Comment: Hi, friend. May i know how the status of this ticket? Did you has any puzzle or question on below explaination.

Comment: I'm considering your answer below to be the accepted answer. I will be adding my voice to the forum post referenced. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid to say, no.

In fact, you can `export` those history out from previous project, and save into excel. **BUT**, what the issue is, we haven't provide such way can for you to `import` the history into new project. So it will be meaningless to export.

Also, based on my known, there hasn't third tool can do pipeline migration. There has such suggestion exists on our official forum: [make it possible to move a Team Project between Team Project Collections](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365365/make-it-possible-to-move-a-team-project-between-te-1.html), and it has taken under review due to strong suggestions from a large number of users. You can vote and comment there.